# Need assistance creating a SQL query that looks inside of a json object and passes variable into the search string

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a database named hobbies and a table called games.
In the games table, I have a field called titles.
In the field titles is a json object.

```
[{
    "titles": ["Double Dragon", "TecmoBowl"]
}]
```

SQL Query

```
select *
from hobbies.games
where  jsonb_path_exists(titles, '$.titles[*] ? (@ == "{{ titles }}")');
```

{{ titles }} is the format for my variable from the web form. When executing the query I get the following error.

> > Query Error: error: function jsonb_path_exists(jsonb,text) does not exist.

My issue is I cannot use a binding variable in this query without it invalidating the request.

I've also tried this example as well without any success.

```
select
from hobbies.games
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(titles, '$.** ? (@.type() == "string" && @ like_regex "{{ 
titles }}")')
```

If I replace the binding variable with the title "Double Dragon" it works as expected but the braces of the variable seem to invalidate my request.
Any help is much appreciated.

How do I pass a variable from a web form into a sql query searching a json object dynamically and still satisfy the string requirements of the jsonb_path_exists command?

Hopefully that makes sense.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I built a system that does this, but instead of passing that directly from the webform into the SQL, I use jinja to render the SQL first, then pass the SQL.  This gives you some better flexibility and control over the kind of SQL you can dynamically generate.

In your example, my webform would still produce a list of titles, but I would use a jinja template like this:

```
select *
from hobbies.games
where title in(
{%- for t in titles %}
'{{ t }}'{{ ', ' if not loop.last else '' }}
{%- endfor -%}
)
```

This would render as,

```
select *
from hobbies.games
where title in(
'Double Dragon',
'TecmoBowl')
```

You can try this out online [here](http://jinja.quantprogramming.com/), to see what I mean.